# Can I implement promises in this case

Tags: javascript, promise

I have to implement promises for the below code ,How to implement promise here,
I want to wait till the for loop ends .and print it .

```js
var a = ['1']; // lets just say array length should not more than 10.  

function addit(id) {
  if (id == 1) {
    a.push(id);
  } else {
    additagain(id);
  }
}):

function additagain(id) {
  a.push(id);

}):

$('.class').each(function(index) {
      id = index + 1;
      addit(id);


    };
```

Comment: What is going on with your code?! `}):` ??

Comment: Your code works synchronously. Promises are for tasks which are asynchronous. Please update your example with a valid use-case and clarify what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Why do you need to use a promise here ? for loops are synchronous

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Why do you need to use promises?

Comment: Actually you could give a better title to this question. Remember this is a free community and people will search by using that info.

Answer (score 0):

Since all these methods are synchronous, implementing a Promise in this case is just a matter of returning a Promise, because the `each` loop will run to completion.

So it could be something as simple as:

```
   return Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
      // Put your code here
   });
```

This example is good to turn any **synchronous** code into a Promise. If you had any asynchronous callback, you would need to use a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , In my original code i have ajax requests going on in the place of addit and additagain so i need promises to stop till the each loops end so that i can access final array.

Comment: In this case your code should be very different, you cannot use `each` if this is your intention. However this answer matches the sample code you put, and I think it should be accepted as the answer in order to not make people confused about that.

Comment: You can open a new question with the correct example otherwise you will pollute this forum with misleading answers for this question.